# What materials can be used to store supercritical water

Tags: water, corrosion

I am wondering which materials might be suitable to contain SCW (supercritical water). Here, we are assuming that the pressure is almost equal on the outside of the container than the inside. I have already considered plastics and some metals but these seem likely to corrode due to how reactive SCW is. Also, it needs to remain sufficiently strong at temperatures around 400°C but not much higher. I've tried to Google it but there doesn't seem to be much literature on the subject

Comment: What specific metals and plastics have you considered? How strong is strong enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlikely any organic compound could be used as a container. Even [polytetrafluoroethylene (PTFE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytetrafluoroethylene) has melting point of 327 °C. [Polyimides](https://omnexus.specialchem.com/selection-guide/polyimide-pi-plastic) can be extruded at 400 °C, so would be too soft.

Some [materials for supercritical water](https://www.supercriticalfluids.com/products/custom-solutions/subcriticalsupercritical-water-systems/) include [Inconel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inconel) and [Hastelloy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haynes_International), nickel-chromium steels.

BTW, if you need an observation port or a non-conductive feed-through, silica-based glasses won't do, since [they dissolve in supercritical water](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0022024895009396). Perhaps sapphire ($\ce{Al2O3}$, corundum) *might* survive for a time, or not -- [supercritical water can etch it](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1134/S1990793117080127) under certain conditions.

You might research the [Benson boiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercritical_steam_generator).